# Vertical fixed position when scroll bugg

Tags: jquery, html, css, sass

I am trying to make something on my site, but it won't work like I have it in mind. 
There is a div on my site with `position: absolute` property. When I scroll down, it has to scroll along the page but when it is like `20px` from the top side from my screen, the element has to be fixed.
The problem is that It works, but when the element has to be `fixed`, it buggs and doesn't do what I want it to do.

I hop it is clear what I have in mind, if not, ask it in a comment and I will try to clarify it.

To make everything more clear, here is a life preview from the bug: http://www.eranmachiels.nl

The code I use:

[HTML]

```
<div class="personalInfo">
    <div class="photo">
        <img src="assets/web-gallery/me.jpg" />
    </div>
    <span class="me">Eran Machiels</span>
    <span class="somethingMore">An 18 years old webdeveloper</span>
</div>
```

[SASS]

```
.personalInfo {
    position: absolute; 
    margin: 0 auto;
    color: #fff;
    @include text-shadow(1px 1px #000);
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 15px;
    z-index: 2;
    width: 212px;

    .photo {
         border: solid 6px #fff;
        overflow: hidden;
        height: 150px;
        width: 150px;
        margin: auto;
        @include border-radius(50%);

        img {
            width: 150px;
            height: 150px;
            margin-left: -2px;
            @include border-radius(50%);
        }
    }   

    .me {
        font-size: 20px;
        font-weight: bold;
        display: block;
    }
}
```

[jQuery]

```
if($(window).scrollTop() + 20 > $('.personalInfo').offset().top) {
    $('.personalInfo').css({
        'position': 'fixed',
        'top': 20
    }).find('.me, .somethingMore').stop().fadeOut(100);


} else {
    $('.personalInfo').css({
        'position': 'fixed',
        'top': $(window).height() / 2 - $('.personalInfo').height() / 2 + 'px'
    }).find('.me, .somethingMore').stop().fadeIn(100);
}
```

The `+20` and the `top: 20` is because I want the element to stop when there are 20 pixels left before it reaches the top of the page.
Perhaps it is something very stupid, but I can't get the solution.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: "top" in the CSS needs a px value not just an number.

Comment: It is not necessary to use px. Just a number works the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't clutter your css and jquery. Make it simple.

**CSS:**

```
.notScrolling{
   position: relative
   margin: 0 auto;
   top: 100px;
}
.whenScrolling {
    position: fixed;
    top: 20px;
    left: 0;
    right:0;
}
```

**Jquery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
function scroll() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= someValue) {
        $('.className').removeClass('notScrolling').addClass('whenScrolling');
    } else {
        $('.className').removeClass('whenScrolling').addClass('notScrolling');
    }
}
document.onscroll = scroll;
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Well, it works but when I resize the window, the `.scrollTop()` value has to be changed. Other it won't work on every screen.

Comment: Managed to fix it. Tried something else from what you said and that worked. You deserve the "check" because you gave the idea for classes. Thanks!

Comment: .scrollTop() is actually based on your window's height. It need not be changed unless there are some css conflicts. And addClass() & removeClass() combo removes the glittering problem due to .css(). Anyways glad that I could be useful.